# How to change signature algorithm to SHA-2 on IIS/Plesk

Tags: iis, plesk

I am getting a this warning in chrome security tab.

Connection - obsolete connection settings
The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with X25519, and AES_256_GCM.
The server signature uses SHA-1, which is obsolete. Enable a SHA-2 signature algorithm instead. (Note this is different from the signature in the certificate.)

[image]

As I have gone through many article and does not seem to be a big issue. Still, can anyone help how I can change the server signature algorithm on IIS/Plesk

Thanks